# Android download file to SD card

Tags: android, android-download-manager, android-fileprovider

I want to allow the user the ability to download a file to the shared android "Download" directory (preferably) on either the internal storage **or** the SD card (if it exists). I can download a file to the internal storage but can't seem to get it to work on the SD card and everything I've looked at on here is either deprecated, incomplete, or doesn't work.

Here's my download code:

```
if(downloadToSdCard) {
    File path = new File(browser.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS), filename);
    Uri downloadsUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(browser, "my.app.fileprovider", path);
    request.setDestinationUri(downloadsUri);
} else {
    request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, filename);
}
downloadManager.enqueue(request);
```

Related bits in my manifest:

```
<application
    android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
    ...>
<provider
    android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
    android:authorities="my.app.fileprovider"
    android:exported="false"
    android:grantUriPermissions="true">
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
        android:resource="@xml/filepaths" />
</provider>
```

And filepaths.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- Used when sharing images from the internet to create a temp image to download to -->
    <cache-path name="shared_images" path="images/"/>
    <cache-path name="text_to_speech_gen" path="text_to_speech_gen/"/>
    <!-- Used when downloading files to allow external apps to open downloaded files -->
    <external-path name="attachment_file" path="."/>
</paths>
```

I'm really struggling to get my head around how the android file system works so explanations with the answer would be appreciated. I've tried reading the official documentation but I just end up falling down endless rabbit holes of confusion. Thanks!

Comment: FileProvider can not be used to serve files from removable micro sd card.

Comment: But DownloadManager can download to removable micro sd card. Take for example full path of Download folder on sd card and then use request.setDestinationUri for full path.

Comment: request.setDestinationUri() can only be used with file uries. Not with content scheme uries. This is a shame Google!

Comment: I'm confused, so can this be done or not? I guess it actually doesn't matter where it ends up I just want to give the user the option of storing on the device vs removable SD card. Thanks!

Comment: Why are you confused? I said: `But DownloadManager can download to removable micro sd card.`

Comment: I thought file URI's are limited in some way in modern android? Like limited to within the app's own directories? i.e. not the SD card. Thanks